# How to make three column template in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am a newbie to CI.And I want to implement a CI in a three column template manner.But I am not sure how can I implement it.The right column is static one once the user logged into the site.It contains like profile pic,Accountinfo and some other stuffs.
In the middle and left columns are going to be  change depend upon the user operation link on the right side.

```
--------------------------------------------
                 Header

Left     |    Middle       |         Right
  Pic    |                 |                
  Account|                 |

                Footer
----------------------------------------------
```

For example if user clicks the  left side link account I need to display account information in the middle panel.So Now the middle panel only changes in content?How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

just display views depending on the method requested..

```
<?php
class Profile extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('profile/home');
    }

    function messages()
    {
        $this->load->view('profile/messages');
    }

    function pictures()
    {
        $this->load->view('profile/pictures');
    }
}
```

and so on.

however it sounds like you want to keep parts of the site the same, so it may be worth looking in to a template library which will allow you to have one layout, but be able to write to specific regions - making the app easier to maintain etc.

see:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/95687/P40/

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template

to summarise - code as required within your controller/model to present the correct view to the user, based on the requested method.